# why won't my onSelect event get fired

Tags: jquery-ui

```
 $.ajax({
            url: $(waterIndexModel.addWaterChargesURL).val(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(waterIndexModel.addWaterChargePlaceHolder).html('');
                $(waterIndexModel.addWaterChargePlaceHolder).html(data);
                $(waterIndexModel.addWaterChargeModal).modal('show');
                $(waterIndexModel.saveWaterChargesBtn).on('click', function () { waterIndexModel.saveWaterCharge() })

                $("#ChargeDate").datepicker({
                    onSelect: function () {
                        $(this).trigger("focus").trigger("blur");
                    }
                });

                waterIndexModel.EnableValidators(waterIndexModel.addWaterChargeForm);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
```

why won't my onSelect event on the datepicker fire? If I am not mistken this should fire when I select a date. As you can see I have simplified it to be as simple as it can be

Comment: Can you put a `alert()` inside `onSelect` and check

Comment: I just have It doesn't appear. Neither does it hit breakpoints I set in the debugger

Comment: does the alert shown?

Comment: so I tried it but no alert

Comment: Can you add the datepicker url that you have loaded?

Comment: you mean javascript file?

Comment: is that an cdn file or yours?

Comment: it's local within the project

Comment: I believe we use jquery ui

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YbLnj/